# Getting error when Adding app in App store

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store

'/Payload/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets/ios/Runner/Info.plist' does not contain a bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally does not contain an executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key from its Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is part of a third-party

If you have any idea please tell me
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update flutter version, this issue [was fixed in version 1.2](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57210)